# How can I get total amount each row using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i want get the each user total amount. i have given table desired output

### User Table

```
user_id  name
 1  Shanmugam
 2  Sharavanan
 3  Selvam
```

Payment Table

```
user_id amount
  1      5
  2      7
  1      5
  2      4
```

i want below output

```
name        total
shanmugam    10
sharavan    11
selvam      0
```

PLease any one help how to write mysql query

i have tried below query
SELECT
    user.name
    SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM
    payment
let join user on user.user_id =payent.user_id

Comment: Can you post the code that tried so far ?

Comment: Hint: `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: SELECT user.name, SUM(payment.amount) as total FROM user INNER JOIN payment ON (user.user_id = payment.user_id) GROUP BY user.user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount) AS total, u.name FROM Payment 
INNER JOIN User AS u ON u.id = p.user_id 
GROUP BY p.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems simply, you can totally finish this by yourself, and note that use `left join`:

```
select
    u.name,
    coalesce(sum(p.amount), 0) as total
from user u
left join payment p
on u.user_id = p.user_id
group by u.user_id
```

See the [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63051/1) here.