# select query from single column to multiple for credit debit from transaction type

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table

```
id | amount | type 
1  | 2000   | cr
2  | 3000   | cr
3  | 4000   | dr
```

I want Result

```
dr   |  cr
4000 |  5000
```

using a single MySQL `SELECT` query.

How to do this?

Comment: Hint: `group by` and `sum`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get total amount each row using mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055855/how-can-i-get-total-amount-each-row-using-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select (select count(amount) from table_name where type='dr') as dr,
 (select count(amount) from table_name where type='cr') as cr from table_name;
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
select sum(amount) as amount, type from [your table] group by type
```

Comment: This seems to be smarter. Then we just calculate diff between two final rows.